# Как на python записать данные в существующий файл Excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

есть такой файл excel [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и мне нужно там, где стоит галочка, написать любой текст для примера и сохранить. Использовал pandas -  он только читал что в файле есть, а мне нужно чтоб записывал в существующий файл

```
df = pd.read_excel('внешний_блок_питания.xlsx')

print(df['Описание*'])
```

[файл можно скачать здесь](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/dKCM/BKeA1S3BJ)

Comment: ваш код приведите.

Comment: @strawdog  я там ничего не написал, я искал как можно это сделать, но не нашел(

Comment: https://pythonbasics.org/write-excel/

Comment: @gil9red тут же создает новый лист от существующего, а мне нужно значение добавить

Comment: @ГорМанучарян, в `sheet_name=` значение того листа, который нужно переписать?

Comment: @gil9red да это я понял,  а дальше допустим я хочу добавить в поле описание, описание какого то продукта, как вот это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то он очень хочется читать ваши килобайнтые многостраничные файлы что-бы показать совершенно элементарные вещи, которые описаны в любом учебнике.

Поэтому мой пример будет на простейшем, одностраничном файле.
Вот файл начальный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меняем значение в одной из колонок. Любой, по вашему выбору. И пишем файл назад.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Книга1.xlsx',header=0)
df['BBB'][2]='ХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХ'
df.to_excel('Книга1.xlsx',header=True, index=False)
```

Смотрим что получилось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь протюнинговать под ваши потребности сумеете самостоятельно.

Comment: спасибо большое я что то типо того делал не получалось, щас все внятно объяснили спасибо большое)